# <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1056)>in jupiter in windows

Tags: python, url, jupyter-notebook, windows-8, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to fetch the URL using below code in jupyter notebook then i'm getting error as 
URLError: .I have tried multiple ways to resolve it but still facing problem.
Sample code

```
def fetch_TR9856():
    """
    Fetch TR9856 dataset for testing multi-word term relatedness

    Returns
    -------
    data : sklearn.datasets.base.Bunch
        dictionary-like object. Keys of interest:
        'X': matrix of 2 words per column,
        'y': vector with scores,
        'topic': vector of topics providing context for each pair of terms

    References
    ----------
    Levy, Ran et al., "TR9856: A multi-word term relatedness benchmark", 2015.

    Notes
    -----
    """
    data = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(_fetch_file(
        'https://www.research.ibm.com/haifa/dept/vst/files/IBM_Debater_(R)_TR9856.v2.zip',
        'similarity', uncompress=True, verbose=0),
        'IBM_Debater_(R)_TR9856.v0.2', 'TermRelatednessResults.csv'), encoding="iso-8859-1")

    # We basically select all the columns available
    X = data[['term1', 'term2']].values
    y = data['score'].values
    topic = data['topic'].values

    return Bunch(X=X.astype("object"), y=y, topic=topic)

#calling the function
tasks = {
    "MEN": fetch_MEN(),
    "WS353": fetch_WS353(),
    "SIMLEX999": fetch_SimLex999(),
    "TR_9856": fetch_TR9856()
}
```

Python Version:3.7.4
Windows 8